# How to keep Mongo db java driver logs into a file?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, mongodb-java

I'm using Mongo db java driver in order to perform some actions on my Mongo db server via my app.
when running my jar, the mongo db driver prints his logs to the screen.
I would like to stop the printing and keep the logs into a file.

can I do this?

Comment: MongoDB Java driver logging uses different Java loggers, depending upon the driver version. Normally, any kind of Java logger (for example java.util.logging) has options / setup to log to the console or a file.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb Java driver uses slf4j logging API. Therefore you can add a logger that implements slf4j API like [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) and an appropriate logback.xml configuration file logging all events to a log file.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.10